# storing the coordinates of a touch stroke into a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsnumber, uitouch

I am trying to record the movement of the users finger and store it as x and y values using nsmutablearrays and nsnumbers, i want to display the values in the console using nslog as soon as touchesEnded is called.

where am i going wrong ?

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint Location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [xScreenLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Location.x]];
    [yScreenLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Location.y]];
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    int a = (int)[xScreenLocations count];
    while  (a >= 0) 
    {
        NSNumber *currentXNumber = [xScreenLocations objectAtIndex:a];
        float currentXInt = currentXNumber.floatValue;
        NSNumber *currentYNumber = [yScreenLocations objectAtIndex:a];
        float currentYInt = currentYNumber.floatValue;
        NSLog(@"%.1f  %.1f",currentXInt,currentYInt);
        a--;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Check if you alloc/init your arrays. The most common mistake.

Comment: Off topic: You can use `[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:location]` to store an object of CGPoint in NSMutableArray. Thus you don't need two arrays for saving the x and y coordinate.

Comment: The initial value of `a` should be "count - 1" because array indexes start from 0 (not 1).

Comment: Neil Galiaskarov, thank you, yes that was the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong index, a is the number of point in the array, you have start from (a - 1) to 0(`[xScreenLocations objectAtIndex:(a - 1)]` instead of `[xScreenLocations objectAtIndex:a]`), you also have to correct you condition in the while loop (`a > 0`) instead of (`a >= 0`).

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    int a = (int)[xScreenLocations count];
    while  (a > 0) 
    {
        NSNumber *currentXNumber = [xScreenLocations objectAtIndex:(a - 1)];
        float currentXInt = currentXNumber.floatValue;
        NSNumber *currentYNumber = [yScreenLocations objectAtIndex:(a - 1)];
        float currentYInt = currentYNumber.floatValue;
        NSLog(@"%.1f  %.1f",currentXInt,currentYInt);
        a--;
    }
}
```

Comment: the main issue was that I didn't alloc/init my arrays, sorry for this stupid mistake, i haven't programmed for iPhone in a while. but your answer was also helpful, i had an off by one error, thanks everyone for the fast reply.